# Update in my WordPress Rest API data not flowing through to React

Tags: react-query, page-refresh

Ok so, I am using a wordpress Api and I am using react-query to retrun the data. The data is apearing as per normal. However, when I update the wordpress Api it is not catching the update. If I want to update the data that has been return in my browser I have to hard refresh.

```js
const Blog = () => {
  const {
    isLoading,
    data,
    isError,
    error,
    isFetching
  } = useQuery(
    'blog-post', fetchBlog, {
      cacheTime: 5000,
    }
  )

  console.log({
    isLoading,
    isFetching,
    data
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p > Loading < /p>
  }
  if (isError) {
    return <p > {
      error.message
    } < /p>
  }
  return ( <
    > {
      data ? .data.map((item, index) => {
        return ( <
          div key = {
            index
          } >
          <
          img src = {
            item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url
          }
          alt = 'image1' / >
          <
          p > {
            item.title.rendered
          } < /p>

          <
          /div>
        )

      })
    } <
    />
  )
}
```

I have tried to use isFetching to have refresh but it just returns as false so it's not reading the change. I am pretty stuck.

I have also tried building the traditional route of using axios.get etc but i have the same issue.

Comment: Please give code as text, it makes it easier to read and work with it.

Comment: @MoritzRingler have add the code as text.

Comment: RQ can't know the Wordpress API has changed.

Comment: @JakubKotrs is that a product of RQ or is there something i can do make that so?

Comment: You would have to built a system that would notify the frontend with react-query about a change on the backend (API). Probably something like websockets. I would not recommend doing that. It's much easier to refetch/reload the page, no?

Comment: @JakubKotrs ay yo i figure it out. i had just had to have the react check if the api data was correct on the page refresh.